# What does SerialPort.isOpen return when the baud rate is wrong?

Tags: c#, serial-port

According to the documentation isOpen returns the open or closed status of a SerialPort. Now if I try to open a port in the correct `COM` number but with the wrong baud rate. In theory the port opens but the two ends cannot communicate. So the isOpen method should return true even though the connection is not proper. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Well the port is still open, so it will return `true`. Of course, you could have tried this quicker than asking a question here!

Comment: Once the serial port is open you can try to send and receive data on it.  The baud rate affects how the data is sent and received but has nothing to do with the port being open or closed.

Comment: @DavidG Well here's the thing, it retuns true in my code but the data is not as it should. And I wanted to know if the problem is with the baud rate or with my code. If the baud rate was wrong and isOpen returns false then it's definately my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can open a Port with a wrong baudrate.
The SerialPort really can't know which baudrate you need, so it will open it, although there is no communicationpartner with same baudrate.

So yes, you are understanding right, it will return true.

Comment: Any ideas on how to test and find the correct baudrate the device is working on?

Comment: What kind of device do you have? 
You could just try out every usual baudrate, like 1200, 2400, 4800 9600 ... and  check if the receiving datastream looks like expected. May you could use Hercules or HTerm for this test.
May you should open a new Question for this.